# Angular 6 http request handling

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm building a web app using Angular 6. I have a service that has a method which when called and given right parameters, sends a POST request to the server and returns the data. This is the method:

```
  public getDataFromServer(request, url): any {
      return this.httpClient.post(url, request, {headers: new HttpHeaders().set(this.headername, this.header ) });
  }
```

Now I have multiple components which uses this method. Every page in the menu (*home, about, news*, etc..) uses this. I want to make a request handler that would send the first request (let's say I login) and then wait until I get a response before sending another request. If I were to click on page *news* and then on page *about* before I would get response, I would already be on page *about* and after I get response the next request will be the one on page *news*, but I'm already on page *about*. I don't want request on *news* to be executed if I'm on page *about*.

I saw some posts with http interceptor, but I don't want the request to even be made to http. Request must not be sent. Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the reason that people don't respond to your question is because it's somewhat of a story. Simplifying your questions like: "I don't want to receive a callback when i have left the page" would increase answers in my opinion.

That being said.

The thing you're looking for is called unsubscribe. httpClient.post returns an Observable on which you probably `.subscribe()` subscribe returns a subscription which you can use to unsubscribe. For example:

```
@Component({etc.etc})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  subscription;

  constructor(private service: Service) {} // Whatever your service is called

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.service.getDataFromServer().subscribe(
      response => {
        console.log(response);
        this.subscription = undefined;
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error);
        this.subscription = undefined;
      }
    );
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.subscription) {
      this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you, this works for most of the stuff. I probably could've written it different. How about if I have a map? When I scroll through the map, it sends requests for checkpoints (so I can display them). I want to send only the last request (when scrolling stops)

Comment: I expressed myself wrongly in the comment. Basically what I meant was, that I don't want to send another request until the last request has been processed. For example, I click on maps and it sends request to server for checkpoints. Even if server hasn't given me back response I can scroll and drag the map around. Every move on google maps makes another request even if the last one has not been processed. I first want to process the last request before sending another, is that achievable using unsubscribe?

Comment: If you want to ignore intermediate requests you can just check if this.subscription == undefined. if true ? make the request, otherwise : ignore.

Comment: yea this works for ignoring all requests, I still need to execute the last request (when the user stop scrolling/dragging)

Comment: Then you need to save all the latest parameters to a variable and check if this variable is set when completing your last request. If so: execute the request with the latest parameters in the variable.